# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : routing not removing index

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm having difficulty to get routing to behave as I would expect. I am using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC.

I have tried many different combination none seem successful. This link was handy but still does not work as expected.

https://geeksarray.com/blog/how-to-use-areas-in-asp-net-core-mvc

I have a few areas in my solution...

I would like it, so that when I do:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "TaskRunLog", new {Area = "Importer", Id = item.Id })
```

the resulting link would be:

```
https://localhost:5001/Org/Paradox/Importer/TaskRunLog/96
```

and not

```
https://localhost:5001/Org/Paradox/Importer/TaskRunLog/Index/96
```

This should be configured globally as a rule and not required to set the route manually.

It doesn't seem to matter what I try, if I hard set it like then it works

```
[Route("Org/{orgName}/[area]/[controller]/{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

In the controller then it works but surely

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

should work if I have the default for the area set like so.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "areaRoute",
  pattern: "Org/{orgName}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
  );
```

Please bare in mind I have tried like several combinations alright.

Comment: Did you match controller class with the `[Area("Importer")]` attribute?

Comment: Check the following documentation regarding the `MapAreaControllerRoute()`: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-area-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-area-route)

Comment: @Jackdaw yes ill include but yes that's already done.

Comment: Hi @Seabizkit, this is the correct url  when you configure route template in startup.cs. It must contains controller and action name.